# Infinite Scroll Loading Content Twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, infinite-scroll

I have the following javascript to load content as users scroll to the bottom of the page but it seems to load the content twice.  Any ideas?

```
var page = <?php echo $next; ?>;
$(window).scroll(function() 
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 1) 
    {
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url : "view.php?q=<?php echo $category; ?>&page="+page
            }).done(function(html){
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                var links = $(html).find('#links');
                $("#content").append(links);
                page = page+1;
                changeUrlParam('page', page);
            })
        }

    })
```

Comment: it actually appears to work correctly if i scroll very very very slowly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My page counter was in the wrong place.  The below works:

```
var page = <?php echo $next; ?>;
$(window).scroll(function() 
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 1) 
    {
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url : "view.php?q=<?php echo $category; ?>&page="+page
            }).done(function(html){
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                var links = $(html).find('#links');
                $("#content").append(links);
                changeUrlParam('page', page);
            })
            page=page+1;
        }

    })
```